# Magento : How to select products by multiple attributes?

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, product-collection, special-price

Trying to get products where `special_price` is set and `special_from_date` is less than todays date and `special_to_date` is more than todays date, so:

```
$currentTime = Mage::getSingleton('core/date')->gmtDate();
$_products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter(
        array(
            array(
                'attribute' => 'promotionactive','promotionactive' => true,
                'and' => array(
                        'attribute' => 'special_from_date','date' => true,'lt' => $currentTime,
                    'and' => array(
                            'attribute' => 'special_to_date','date' => true,'gt' => $currentTime,
                        'and' => array( 
                                'special_price' => true)
                        ),
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    ;
```

Today I simplified it a bit but it still won't get products properly. The filter is set to select only if promotionactive is true but in results I can see all the products regardless if is true or false.

Finally the code is doing it's job:

```
$currentTime = Mage::getSingleton('core/date')->gmtDate();
$_products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('promotionactive' , true);
$id = $_products->getFirstItem()->getId();
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
if(($_product['promotionactive'] == True) && (($_product['special_price'])==True) && (strtotime($_product->getSpecialFromDate()) < strtotime($currentTime)) && (strtotime($currentTime) < strtotime($_product->getSpecialToDate()))){
    $milliEnd = strtotime($_product->getSpecialToDate()) * 1000;
    $productUrl = $_product->getUrlInStore();
}else{
    //some code
}
```

Problem solved, thanks everyone.

If there is any way to make it better please post below ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code :

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$collection->addMinimalPrice()
            ->addFinalPrice()
            ->addTaxPercents()
            ->addUrlRewrite(); 
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($collection);
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($collection);

$collection->getSelect()->where("`price_index`.price !=price_index.min_price");
$now = Mage::getSingleton('core/date')->gmtDate();
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('special_from_date', array('or'=> array(
    0 => array('date' => true, 'to' => $now),
    1 => array('is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('null')))
), 'left');
```

Comment: Your example is giving me a huge chunk of data in which actually I can't find anything interesting like products with adequate parameters, I changed a bit my script and now it gives me only a product with selected attributes.